# How to determine what list a subset is a part of and print the name?

Tags: python-3.x, list, search, nested, set

#### I would like to determine whether a list of strings can be found within a nested set that is in list in python and print what list or set of lists that it was found in.

For example:

```
list1 = ['cat','red']

animal = ['iguana','cat','spider','monkey','dog']
color = ['yellow','red','blue','purple','green','orange']
action = ['run','jump','swim','fly']

list2 = [animal,color,action]

list1 = set(list1)

for category in list2
    if list1.issubset(type)
        print(list1, "is part of", category)
```

and the result should be:

```
['cat','red'] is a part of [animal,color]
```

my attempts have either failed or instead I get:

*['iguana','cat','spider','monkey','dog']*

Which is the animal array, but I just want the term animal and color instead.

Is there any way to search through the nested list and print what list it is a part of?

Comment: in your "print" you should use `type` rather than `list2[type]`. Note that there are a bunch of `:` missing and the use of `type` as a variable name is a poor as it would make `type(list1)` not work. Your print is also not a valid print statement :-)

Comment: I think I have edited the question to clear up any confusions you might have. Let me know if I need to explain it a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to be using the actual characters making up the variable names *in* the code. As such, you'll need to explicitly define the category of each list:

```
list1 = ['cat','red']

animal = ("animal", ['iguana','cat','spider','monkey','dog'])
color = ("color", ['yellow','red','blue','purple','green','orange'])
action = ("action", ['run','jump','swim','fly'])

list2 = [animal,color,action]

matches = []

for item in list1:
    for category in list2:
        if item in category[1]:
            matches.append(category[0])
print(list1, "is part of", matches)
```

A precondition here is that you're guaranteed to find a match for each member of `list1` *somewhere* in `list2`.

Comment: Worked well, almost forgot adding the "animal" tag into the list animal was placed. It prints exactly what I wanted using this code.